# why does this Aminor "augmented" progression resolve in Gmajor?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I am currently discovering the fretboard through the lens of the augmented chords, meaning that I am playing around with augmented triads and by lowering/raising a note here and there creating minor/major chords and forming progressions. During this exploring of the fretboard I ran into a chord progression where Aminor resolves in Gmajor.

Below is pictures of the chords in order by the progression. I have inverted the chords so that the root is where I perceive it after having derived the chord from an augmented triad.. (For example the second chord is technically a Eb6, but to me this is a Cminor chord because what I did was raising the B in a Ebaugmented to create the notes C-G-Eb.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively what you’ve got here is two plagal cadences. You have `Am - Cm - G - Dm - C - Ebaug - G`. So in the context of G mixolydian this would be `II - IVb - I - V - IV - bVI - I`. Note that `II,IV,IVb,bIV` all have a subdominant character, while the (minor) `V` does not have a clear character. So in the end this is functionally equivalent to doing `IV - I - IV - I`.

Comment: The final three chords — C  Ebaug  G — bears a very strong resemblance to the common C Cm G (IV iv I) progression found in many songs, reinforcing the point about the IV - I relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your E♭aug -> G chord progression has great voice leading. All that changes between those two chords is that the E♭ in the E♭aug chord goes down one semitone to the D in the G chord. The rest of the notes in both chords stay put.

Great voice leading is powerful enough to carry an entire chord progression, I've found.